# Alternative proof: Matrix $A$ is similar to $B$ iff $\lambda I - A$ is equivalent to $\lambda I - B$

Tags: linear-algebra

We have this theorem for square matrices $A,B$ over a field $K$, and $\lambda$ an indeterminate:

> If $\lambda I - A$ is equivalent to $\lambda I - B$, then $A$ is similar to $B$.
>
> ($A$, $B$ are matrices in $K^{n\times n}$, and $\lambda I - A$ is the characteristic matrix of $A$).

(**Note** The word "equivalent" above means that you can get one from the other by doing row operations and column operations: a sequence of elementary operations on rows or on columns: add multiple of one row to another, swap two rows, or multiply one by an invertible scalar, or similar operations for columns. In this case the equivalence allows polynomial scalars in $K[\lambda]$).

The proof which I'm aware of is very ... "calculation-style": It first proved a lemma, (something like $M(\lambda) = P(\lambda)(\lambda I - A) + R$), then show you the result is correct by doing some calculations. (I think there is good chance that you know which proof I am talking about).

After reading the proof, I still have no idea why it is true. Knowing a proof usually helps you understanding something, but for this one, it confuses me.

**So, my question is:**

Is there an alternative proof for this theorem, (undergraduate level), that helps me to understand what's going on.

Comment: What does "equivalent" in "$\lambda I - A$ is equivalent to $\lambda I - B$" mean? Similar?

Comment: Are you reading Gantmacher's book?

Comment: Matrix equivalence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence

Comment: @TroyWoo No, why? It has the same proof or an alternative one? It will not surprise me if it has the same one, I looked up three texts, they all use the same proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer Please see the Note.

Comment: I think that you should state the theorem more precisely: what values is $\lambda$ free to take? Since in this form it is obviously false: take $\lambda =0$.

Comment: @pppqqq I guess the intended meaning is that it holds true for all $\lambda$

Comment: @pppqqq Polynomial matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never heard this terminology. I assume it means $\exists P,Q\in GL(n,\mathbb K)$ such that $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb K$, $\lambda I - A=P^{-1}(\lambda I -B)Q$, right?

Comment: This used to be a MathOverflow question long ago: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66269/on-similar-matrices-and-polynomial-matrices

Comment: @NotanID Just browse through the first volume of Gantmacher. Its somewhere there, I read it last year, but not quite intuitive, so I forgot ;P. I think it reflects the work of Gantmacher on bimodules. Its quite interesting you asked such a question, since people no longer receive that kind of education (its a must read in the 80's). You working on linear system theory?

Comment: @TroyWoo Thanks for the ref., will see to it. No, it's just a hobby

Comment: @darijgrinberg That question asked three years ago, and still no answer...

Comment: @pppqqq Not sure what $GL(n, K)$ means, I added a note for "equivalent", you can see that if you're still interested.